# Propper conversion of PHP and SQL data types

Tags: php, mysql

A seemingly minor problem are bothering me, something that should have a simple solution. I am currently running a server and a database, the database which contains data that I want to use in a PHP request on a website. I have created a function in PHP that does the following:

```
function getUserID($val){
     include("config.php");
     $conn = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname) or die($conn);
     $sql = "SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username=?";
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bind_param("s", $val);
     $stmt->execute();
     $result = $stmt->get_result();
     if(getUserExist($val)){
          $rowdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
          $conn->close();
          return $rowdata['userid'];
     }
}
```

This works just fine.. HOWEVER. The returned data type, which is supposed to be an Integer ( 1, 2, 3, 4... etc. ), returns a value similar to an JSON object or int(1), depending on how I write it.

```
array(1) { ["userid"]=> int(4) }
```

I have tried:

1. `$rowdata['userid']`
2. `$rowdata`

How do I make the function return purely the integer value? When it is added to the database with following code-snippet:

```
...
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user1, user2, user3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("isi", $user1, $user2, $user3);
        $user1 = $_POST[getUserID($username)];
        $user2 = $_POST['val2'];
        $user3 = $_POST['val3'];
        $stmt->execute();
        
        $stmt->close();
    }
    $conn->close();
```

As mentioned, it retrieves data just fine, it is just the value that acts in an odd way. When this code is executed, $user1 or rather the final value within database has the value of NULL. (database accepts only integers in that slot).

Comment: What do you mean by returning it as a JSON object? Do you mean it's a string instead of integer?

Comment: [`json_decode()`](https://3v4l.org/k3TdD)?

Comment: What is this `or die($conn)`? This is not a valid PHP code

Comment: @Barmar Ah well I need to elaborate and make that clearer. I found it to have similarities to a JSON object. The result from var_dump($rowdata); is:  array(1) { ["userid"]=> int(4) }

Similar to JSON.

Comment: So it is entirely on your control when to obtain the complete result-set and when to obtain the integer, right?

Comment: @hakre
You could say that, yeah. I retrieve the data using the following command: 
SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username='someuser';.. I could retrieve the whole user and its data but I think that would be a waste when it wont be used.

Comment: @shummy That's just how var_dump() works. The point of var_dump() is to dump information about the variable, so instead of just giving you the integer it also tells you that it is an integer. The integer itself shouldn't be affected by that. What value does `echo $rowdata['userid']` return?

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` then? Why not fetch only the single column?

Comment: @olafmoriarty
Ah... I see. Then the problem might be elsewhere if it returns the value properly. I will have to look into that. 
When it comes to the "echo $rowdata['userid'];" command, I must have written it wrong as it causes the site to shut down.. so that will be a mystery.

Comment: @hakre
I am fairly new to PHP, and from what I found while reading that was the command to use. Could you elaborate on fetching the single column? Currently the function retrieves only one value, which is the ID of that given user.

Comment: It retrieves one result row (and the result row has only one value). You could use `$value = mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0]`, feel free to browse the PHP manual to explore the many options the mysqli extension offers. This is likely out of scope for Stackoverflow, so I just leave it as a comment.

Comment: I will look into it, thank you @hakre. My book around PHP is still on the road, hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if the problem does not lie in `getUserID()`, but in this line:

```
$user1 = $_POST[getUserID($username)];
```

What you're doing here is **not** setting `$user1` to the value of `getUserID()` - instead, you're setting it to "the element in the `$_POST` array which has a key of whatever `getUserID()` returns". And there are very few scenarios where that makes sense.

I'm assuming the line you want to replace it with is

```
$user1 = getUserID($username);
```

Comment: I completely missed that. You are correct, that was the mistake I had made. Thank you!
Been on this witchhunt for hours.